# Computed prop in VueJS not updated until input lost focus

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, computed-properties, vue-reactivity

same as title says. A computed property from a object it´s not reactive until the input box lost the focus.

But if the object is in data, the value changes as soon as changed in the input.

I created a codepen with the example: https://codepen.io/Albvadi/pen/QWwMOQV

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Match Component</div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-4 text-right">{{homeTeam.desc}}</div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <input class="form-control text-center" type="number" min="0" v-model.number="homeTeam.score" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <input class="form-control text-center" type="number" min="0" v-model.number="awayTeam.score" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">{{ awayTeam.desc }}</div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  DATA:
                  <b>{{ homeTeam.score }}</b>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    COMPUTED:
                    <b>{{ awayTeam.score }}</b>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#container",
  data: {
    homeTeam: {
      name: "SPA",
      desc: "Spain",
      score: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    awayTeam: function() {
      return {
        name: "GER",
        desc: "Germany",
        score: 0
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
  }
});
```

If you change the first input, the data value is changed inmediate.
If you change the second input, the computed value if changed only when input lost focus.

How can I solve this?

**== EDIT ==**

Thanks for your answers!
I know that putting awayteam in the data section solves the problem, it was just an example to simplify my problem.

My problem was that along with the two results, I wanted to have a computed property to be able to issue to another component.
I edited the codepen with the final result: https://codepen.io/Albvadi/pen/jOELYwN and it´s working correctly.

But @Sami Kuhmonen comments that computed properties are only read properties but in my `checkFinalResult` I´m setting the `computedMatch`..
It´s the right approach??

Comment: Computed values shouldn’t be changed. They’re *computed* from other data and therefore read only.

Comment: Thank you! Can you check my edit?

Comment: You never set anything in computed properties. That’s the right approach. So you’re still doing things wrong. If you really need to modify computed data then do every single field inside it refer to a field in `data` and then you can modify those as much as you want. Just like you already do with some of them.

Comment: Thank you again. If you want, post your comment as an answer and I´ll check it as the correct answer. I think it´s the most helpful comment for my question... I´ll try to refactor my data to not set anything in the computed property... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties should be considered read only. Every time there's a change in the properties they reference their value is computed from other values and all changes are lost (or at least should be thought that way, there may be cases where some values remain). Even though sometimes changing their properties seems to work it's not guaranteed and they may change whenever.

In the codepen you already have the computed property referencing other properties from the object, so you'll have to add all the things you want to change similarly and then change that value. This will cause the computed value to be re-evaluated and the changes will be visible and persisted.

Note that building a computed object from a lot of separate things might not be the most performant way and it depends on the situation how it should be handled. If the values are only used within the component then it's easy to just use them directly but if you need an object of specific form for something and need it reactive then computed property might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, why this computed property does not update `DOM` element instantly,because it has no `data` reference with `Vue` instance.Here, it return some `static` value only,which was not the `computed` property's purpose. `computed property` came to purpose,when you need to calculate or compute some decision on the basis of your `data property` of your `vue` instance.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#container",
  data: {
    homeTeam: {
      name: "SPA",
      desc: "Spain",
      score: 0
    },
    awayTeam: {
      name: "GER",
      desc: "Spain",
      score: 0
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Match Component</div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-4 text-right">{{homeTeam.desc}}</div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <input class="form-control text-center" type="number" min="0" v-model.number="homeTeam.score" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <input class="form-control text-center" type="number" min="0" v-model.number="awayTeam.score" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">{{ awayTeam.desc }}</div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  DATA:
                  <b>{{ homeTeam.score }}</b>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    COMPUTED:
                    <b>{{ awayTeam.score }}</b>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a computed property for this task? I would simply do it this way.

```
  new Vue({
     el: "#container",
     data: {
        homeTeam: {
        name: "SPA",
       desc: "Spain",
       score: 0
     },
    awayTeam:  {
       name: "GER",
       desc: "Germany",
       score: 0
     },
   },
   mounted() {
      console.log("Component mounted.");
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you check the edit for recommend the best approach?